# Counting Occurrences of IP Addresses & Exporting Results to CSV

Tags: regex, powershell, parsing, filtering, logfile

I have data in a CSV file that looks like this:

```
src_ip,dst_ip,tran_src_ip,tran_dst_ip,srczone,src_country_code,dstzone,dst_country_code
75.76.77.78,23.24.25.26,192.168.1.100,192.168.1.18,"""""WAN""""",USA,"""""LOCAL""""",USA
75.76.77.78,23.24.25.26,,192.168.1.21,"""""WAN""""",USA,"""""LOCAL""""",USA
12.13.14.15,23.24.25.26,,192.168.1.21,"""""WAN""""",USA,"""""LOCAL""""",USA
23.24.25.26,23.24.25.26,192.168.1.100,192.168.1.18,"""""WAN""""",USA,"""""LOCAL""""",USA
```

I want to be able to import that file, look at the values within the `src_ip` column, and create a new CSV file that will contain a column showing the `src_ip`, and how many times that address showed up in the input file.

I've found code like this that can find a particular pattern, but it's not working well for me when I enter a regex for IP addresses. I also am unsure how to have it return the IP address, along with the number of occurrences for that particular IP.

```
$regex = '\b(\w+)=([^ ]+)'    
(Select-String -Path 'input_file.csv' -Pattern $regex -AllMatches |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Matches).Count
```

Ideally, I would like the output to look something like this.

```
src_ip,Occurances
75.76.77.78,2
12.13.14.15,1
23.24.25.26,1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you run into a "count occurrences of *foo* in *bar*" problem (particularly if *bar* is a CSV) `Group-Object` is usually the tool of choice:

```
Import-Csv 'input.csv' |
    Group-Object src_ip -NoElement |
    Select-Object Name, Count |
    Export-Csv 'output.csv' -NoType
```

If you want different column headers use calculated properties in the `Select-Object` step:

```
... | Select-Object @{n='src_ip';e={$_.Name}}, @{n='Occurrences';e={$_.Count}} | ...
```

Comment: When not using the Group property, I'd add `-NoElement`